# MVC C# Correct way to extend property on DB class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm sure this is an easy solve, but for some reason I can't seem to figure it out. I'm looking to add a property to an auto-generated class without adding it to the dynamically created class directly since that property would be deleted every time the model is updated.

```
//database  <auto-generated> template
public partial class AwesomeClassName
{
    public int TableID{ get; set;}
    public int ForeignID {get; set;}
    public int ContactID {get; set;}
}

//extended class
public class AwesomeClassNameMod : AwesomeClassName
{
    public string fullname{get; set;}

}

public class AwesomeClassViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<AwesomeClassNameMod> AwesomeClassNameModList { get; set; }
    //Shouldn't I be able to access 
    //  AwesomeClassNameModList.TableID
    //  AwesomeClassNameModList.ForeignID
    //  AwesomeClassNameModList.ContactID
    //  AwesomeClassNameModList.fullname

    //.... other viewmodel properties
}
```

So that will compile fine and all, but when you try to select something from the table I get an unable to cast error.

```
IEnumerable<AwesomeClassNameMod> acm = (IEnumerable<AwesomeClassNameMod >)db.AwesomeClassName.Where(a => a.ForeignID == 1);
```

What easy thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `AwesomeClassName` is `partial`., you should make another class named `AwesomeClassName` in a different file, also with the `partial` modifier. Then any properties in both locations should be pulled together each time you make a new instance of `AwesomeClassName`.

Comment: @NicholasV. Life saver! wow do I feel dumb.